# How can I modify my code so I can add a body parameter to the post request

Tags: android, json, post, httprequest, internal-server-error

I have a project in which I have some urls, each leading to an endpoint. I have connect to those endpoints via a post request with a JSON in which I have to insert a parameter (i.e.: "email":"mail@etc.com") in order to get a token that I will put in the body of the next request of the endpoint I want to connect to.

I tried using addRequestProperty() and setRequestProperty() and I can't figure what is wrong. In log it appears that I get an internal server error (code 500) when trying to make the http requests.

I have an endpoint to which I don't have to pass any parameters and that works fine, providing a list of "stuff", each having an id in its JSON result from the endpoint. Then I have to take every id so when I click on a "stuff" from the list on the screen another endpoint is called providing me results with that "stuff"'s details in another activity - for this endpoint I need to pass for any item I click its specific id taken from the earlier JSON result.

private static String makeHttpRequestGetUser(URL url) throws IOException {

```
    String jsonResponse = "";

    if(url == null)
        return jsonResponse;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("email", "t1@gmail.com");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();

        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error response code in GetUser request: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem retrieving the "stuff" JSON result.", e);
    } finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        if(inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
    }

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

---

private static String extractTokenFromJson(String spotJSON) {

```
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(spotJSON))
        return null;

    String tokenValue = "";

    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(spotJSON);
        JSONObject result = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("result");
        tokenValue = result.getString("token");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem parsing the token", e);
    }

    return tokenValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first why you don`t use Volley(recommended by google) library for communicating with your rest APIs?
If you decided to change it to volley start it here : 
[Volley Library for Android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) and make it more easier with a small class that i wrote before[VolleyWebClient](https://github.com/ravaee/VoleyWebclient) you just need to add it in your project and enjoy.

But in order to your own code i think the 500 error in response shows the content-type of your request is missing. usually to get token you can use Form content-type like this:

```
setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I wish it will help you and save your day.

Comment: Hey, Ravaei! Thank you for taking your time to answer! I will take a look at the Volley library and try to change it if it's simpler. Also, thak you for the feedback on my code!